# Showing just some events from Google Calendar

Tags: google-calendar, embed

Is it possible to filter events for a Google Calendar embed? We are a multi-branch library system, and each library has it's own calendar. However I'd like to display a calendar that listed all of the events for Kids or Seniors.

As far as I can tell there is no way to categorize or tag individual events, so my thought was to put "tags" in the title. So have events named like:

```
Author Talk: Tom Angelberger [Kids]
Author Talk: David Baldacci [Adults]
Holiday Craft: Make a snowflake [All Ages]
```

and then for the kids calendar only display the [Kids] or [All Ages] tagged events.

I've looked only and through the API and can't quite figure out how to do it. The main portion of the website is done in PHP and I've got a little experience with jQuery so I guess I might have to extract the data programmatically but I'm not really sure where to start.

Answer (score 1):

Google Calendar unfortunately [doesn't](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2011/05/google-calendar-adds-event-colors.html) offer support for labels (Google's name for tag): the best you can do is add your own tag as you did, or create one calendar per tag.